# NHibernate: Conditionally load a calculated column

Tags: nhibernate, subquery, calculated-columns

I have the following proprty

```
<property name="Allocated" type="decimal" formula="(select sum(a.AllocationAmount) from  Allocation a where  a.TransactionId = TransactionId)" />
```

This loads the amount of a Transaction that has been allocated to invoices which is working beautifully.

However, is most cases I don't care about this amount. Is there a way to conditionally load this calculated column? Or is there a way to add this calculated column to HQL/Critera so I can just make it part of some specific queries that I run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NH 3.0 you can define lazy properties, which work exactly as they sound (see http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/27/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties.aspx)

However, this looks more suited for a query OR maybe a pseudo-entity that acts as a view.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify `access="none"` on the property mapping, you can keep the property out of your object model all together, yet still query on it using hql. See [this article](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/10/nhibernate-ndash-query-only-properties.aspx) for further information.

Also, you could factor that logic into a function, register it with a custom dialect and then query/project on it using the criteria api (via `Projections.SqlFunction` )